# Текст из TextView на стену ВКонтакте

Tags: android, вконтакте

Сделал свое небольшое первое приложение, в котором хочу сделать так, чтобы текст из `TextView` можно было опубликовать на стену ВКонтакте нажатием на кнопку.

Как это можно реализовать?

P.S. знаю php и MySQL.

Comment: http://vk.com/dev/android_sdk - читаем-изучаем, а потом если что-то не будет получаться можете спросить.

Comment: я не понимаю идея самой реализации